# Экспорт html (php) в DOC

Tags: export, php, ms-word

Здравствуйте, имеется некоторая страница, формируемая php и запросами к БД. Необходимо ее передать в doc файл при этом сохранив все рисунки (не абсолютные ссылки на сервер, а вшитые в сам doc). Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты реализации. Уже битый день маюсь..

Answer (score 0):

Источник: https://web.archive.org/web/20150627063926/demura.su/articles/php/sozdaem_doc_fajl_cherez_php/

Сделаем шаблон нашего будущего документа.

```
 $WORD = 'MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Location:
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<html xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">
<meta name=3DProgId content=3DWord.Document>
<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Word 11">
<meta name=3DOriginator content=3D"Microsoft Word 11">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3D"test.files/filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Print</w:View>
  <w:GrammarState>Clean</w:GrammarState>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel>
 </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState=3D"false" LatentStyleCount=3D"156">
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Tahoma";}
@page Section1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:18.0pt 19.3pt 18.0pt 18.0pt;
    mso-header-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-footer-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.Section1
    {page:Section1;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"\041E\0431\044B\0447\043D\0430\044F \0442\0430\0431\043B\=
0438\0446\0430";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin:0cm;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
    mso-ansi-language:#0400;
    mso-fareast-language:#0400;
    mso-bidi-language:#0400;
    width:100%;
}

td.br1{
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <h1 align=3D"center">Первый файл DOC сделанных с помощью PHP и HTML</h3>

    <p>В теле документа вы можете использовать любые HTML теги для разметки. </p>

</body>

</html>';
```

Все делается с помощью HTML разметки, вставьте таблицу, задайте цвет текста, выравнивание, курсив и жирность и у вас появится отличный документ. Единственное что нужно помнить это префикс 3D который нужен для правильного понимания формата в тексте в теге H1 у тега align есть префикс 3D.

Дальше с нашей готовой строкой можно делать что угодно, допустим запишем её в файл на сервере.

```
$fp = fopen ("firstfile.doc", "w");
fwrite($fp,$WORD);
fclose($fp);
```

Ну а дальше делайте с этим файлом что хотите и как хотите. Попробуйте указать пути к картинкам, возможно они и отобразятся в документе (не уверен).
P.S. doc файл был проверен в MSWord 2007-2010.

Comment: спасибо, натыкался на это в поисковике, но этот способ не позволяет "вшить картинки" в doc, а значит не подходит.. 
Сейчас наткнулся на http :// phpword . codeplex . com, пока разбираюсь, но уже появилась надежда что с задачей справлюсь

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что текст взят из моего блога, т.к. я хоть и и брал материал с первого источника, но код и текст изменил.

или я ошибаюсь @Александр Маслов?

Comment: @alexxxer1234, а если вместо http-ссылок использовать data uri?